# evol.distinct funciton (Picante) in parallel

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am currently trying to run in parallel a loop of the evol.distinct function (Picante package in R) with no success.

The original code is:

```
#read trees
phy<-read.nexus("output.nex")

#Create matrix
ed_calc=matrix(nrow=length(phy[[1]]$tip.label), ncol=length(phy))

#Calculate ED for all the trees (the loop I want to run in parallel)
for(i in 1:length(phy)){
    print(i)
    newdata=evol.distinct(phy[[i]],type= "fair.proportion")
    ed_calc[,i] <-newdata[order(newdata[,1]),][,2]
    #names(ed_calc)[,i]=i
  }

#Convert to data frame
ed_calc=as.data.frame(ed_calc)

#Species names as rownames 
rownames(ed_calc)=newdata[order(newdata[,1]),][,1]

write.table(ed_calc, file = "ED_Allpar.txt", append = FALSE, quote = TRUE, sep = " ",
            eol = "\n", na = "NA", dec = ".", row.names = TRUE,
            col.names = TRUE, qmethod = c("escape", "double"),
            fileEncoding = "")

ed_calc_all= rowMedians(as.matrix(ed_calc))

write.table(ed_calc_all, file = "ED_Medianpar.txt", append = FALSE, quote = TRUE, sep = " ",
            eol = "\n", na = "NA", dec = ".", row.names = TRUE,
            col.names = TRUE, qmethod = c("escape", "double"),
            fileEncoding = "")
```

I've tried with foreach, with no succeed :'(. Please, help. data are in (https://www.dropbox.com/sh/uftq7iu1qv9h3te/AACF7jWh0HA8mv1hN8WhItERa?dl=0)

Thanks for any help you could give me,

Edited:

My OS is manjaro Linux. The code I used to parallelize is:

```
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)
parallel::detectCores()
## [1] 8
n.cores <- parallel::detectCores()

#create the cluster
my.cluster <- parallel::makeCluster(
  n.cores-6,
  type = "FORK"
)
#check cluster definition (optional)
print(my.cluster)
#register it to be used by %dopar%
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl = my.cluster)
#check if it is registered (optional)
foreach::getDoParRegistered()
foreach::getDoParWorkers()

foreach (i=1:length(phy),combine='rbind') %dopar% {
  print(i)
  newdata=evol.distinct(phy[[i]],type= "fair.proportion")
  ed_calc[,i] <-newdata[order(newdata[,1]),][,2]
  ed_calc=as.data.frame(ed_calc)
}

stopCluster(my.cluster)
#Convert to data frame
ed_calc=as.data.frame(ed_calc)

#Species names as rownames 
rownames(ed_calc)=newdata[order(newdata[,1]),][,1]

write.table(ed_calc, file = "ED_Allpar.txt", append = FALSE, quote = TRUE, sep = " ",
            eol = "\n", na = "NA", dec = ".", row.names = TRUE,
            col.names = TRUE, qmethod = c("escape", "double"),
            fileEncoding = "")

ed_calc_all= rowMedians(as.matrix(ed_calc))

write.table(ed_calc_all, file = "ED_Medianpar.txt", append = FALSE, quote = TRUE, sep = " ",
            eol = "\n", na = "NA", dec = ".", row.names = TRUE,
            col.names = TRUE, qmethod = c("escape", "double"),
            fileEncoding = "")
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Can you provide some detail of what kind of assistance you are looking for? Which is the error message thrown when you run the code? It's at the end of all the code the error is thrown? Also you have mentioned 'in parallel' and included `Parallel-processing` as a tag... but I do not see the `Parallel` package...

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. I just edited the message including the required information. :D

Comment: `foreach()` is _not_ the same as for-loop! Accepting that is essential to understanding how to parallelize a for loop. See <https://www.jottr.org/2019/01/11/parallelize-a-for-loop-by-rewriting-it-as-an-lapply-call/> for solutions and limitations.